# MySQL: What uniquely identifies a constraint? (What is a catalog?)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to reflect on MySQL  to list out keys (PKs *and* non-null UNIQUEs) on a table. I'm looking at `information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` and `information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`, and would like to join the two (to search for columns without `NOT NULL`). They both have `CONSTRAINT_(CATALOG|SCHEMA|NAME)` — what is `CONSTRAINT_CATALOG`? Do I need it in my join? (On one server, its always `def`, on another, `NULL`)

What *uniquely* identifies a constraint, i.e., what's the PK on the `information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` table? (MySQL helpfully does not declare it to have one…)

My suspicion is that it is `(TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME)` (i.e., without catalog name), but I'd like to confirm…